# Flutter firebase how to sign in users with google

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

hi i'm trying to sign in and sign up users using google with Firebase  so to sign up users i'm doing this

```
 void handleGoogleSignIn() async{

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser=await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential=
    GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: 
    googleAuth.accessToken);

    user =(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
 }
```

so i need to how to sign in users using google the  above code
`user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);` seems to just create a new user if it doesn't exist but i need to login user with google to their existing account in my app not create a new user if it doesn't exist so how do i implement that

Comment: "seems to just create a new user if it doesn't exist", do you mean even though they have an account it just overwrites their old information?

Comment: Nope I just want to sign in users not create an new account  so if a new user who hasn't signed up  with there google account  tries to sign in  it  shouldn't create an account  for them which the above code does  I believe .in the case of registering  user with email and password we have signInWithEmailAndPassword() which signs in user not creates a new user so  how to do the same with google I am super new to this stuff hope it make sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this to handle sign in with a google account:

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
       // hold the instance of the authenticated user
       FirebaseUser user;
       // flag to check whether we're signed in already
       bool isSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
       if (isSignedIn) {
          // if so, return the current user
          user = await _auth.currentUser();
       }
       else {
          final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = 
             await _googleSignIn.signIn();
          final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = 
             await googleUser.authentication;
          // get the credentials to (access / id token)
          // to sign in via Firebase Authentication 
          final AuthCredential credential =
             GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
                idToken: googleAuth.idToken
             );
          user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
       }

 
   return user;
}
```

Comment: But if if a new user is trying to log in it will create an account right I don't want to create an account for an user I want to log in the user . To sign up the user I think the code works I want to check if the user has created an account in my firebase app if not tell them to sign up